# how to make a certain type of matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I make a matrix with some texts around it as bellow?

[image]

Comment: Look for `nicematrix`

Comment: Excellent @egreg. I've just had a look: it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once used the kbordermatrix package ([http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Ekcborder/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf)) for a similar problem if that helps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}

    \[
    H = \kbordermatrix{
          & A  & B  & C  & D  \\
        A & Ha &    &    &   \\ 
        B &    & Hb &    &   \\
        C &    &    & Hc &   \\
        D &    &    &    & Hd 
        }
    \]
\end{document}
```

or like that ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\newcommand{\mLabel}[1]{\mbox{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}}
\begin{document}
   
        \[
        H=
    \begin{blockarray}{c@{}ccc@{\hspace{5pt}}cl}
        & \mLabel{A} & \mLabel{B} & \mLabel{C} &\mLabel{D} & \\
        \begin{block}{[c@{\hspace{10pt}}ccc@{\hspace{10pt}}c]l}
            & Ha &    &    &    & \mLabel{A} \\
            &  ´ & Hb &    &    & \mLabel{B} \\
            &    &    & Hc &    & \mLabel{C} \\
            &    &    &    & Hd & \mLabel{D} \\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want the text column A, B, C, D to be on the right? You have any ideas?

Comment: @ĐạtLêThành Just put a \array after it with one column?

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
H = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col]
A  & B  & C  & D  & \\
Ha &    &    &    & A \\ 
   & Hb &    &    & B \\
   &    & Hc &    & C \\
   &    &    & Hd & D
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Yes, I've managed to do the same.